# Set background color of the td padding according to the dropdown value from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

For the code below, when the value in the select menu change, the bg color of td change. Now, i had retrieved the selected value from the database and have it shown on the select menu.
I'm wondering is there any way to change the bg color of the td cell based on the selected database value.
Thanks in advance.

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() === 'ok') {
    $(this).parent().css({
      'background-color': 'orange'
    });
  } else {
    $(this).parent().css({
      'background-color': 'pink'
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding='15'>
  <th>Confirm</th>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="ok">OK</option>
        <option value="cancel">Cancel</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr><br>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="ok">OK</option>
        <option value="closed">Cancel</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr><br>
</table>
```

This's my PHP to retrieve the selected database value

```
<td><select name="status[]">

<option value="open" <?php if ($row['status'] == 'ok') echo 
'selected="selected"'; ?> > ok</option>
<option value="closed" <?php if ($row['status'] == 'cancel') echo 
'selected="selected"';?> >cancel</option>
  </select></td>
```

Comment: It seems that you have it all figured out. What is the problem?

Comment: use id of your bg

Comment: Also note that the location you've put the `<br />` tags is invalid; they cannot be children of a `table`

Comment: it only works when there's a change in the selected menu value. But when the selected menu show the selected value from the database ie. cancel, no color is being applied. I want the td bg to turn pink when the retrieved database value is "cancel" .

Comment: In that case you should have shown us the relevant code where you're setting the value of the select programmatically. Could you please edit the question to include it

Comment: Updated, please have a look, thanks

Comment: Thanks, I added an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you set the values in your PHP code when the page loads. This means that no `change` event occurs to set the background colours. To fix this, simply trigger a `change` event on load of the page:

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() === 'ok') {
    $(this).parent().css({
      'background-color': 'orange'
    });
  } else {
    $(this).parent().css({
      'background-color': 'pink'
    });
  }
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding='15'>
  <th>Confirm</th>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="ok">OK</option>
        <option value="cancel" selected="true">Cancel</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr><br>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="ok">OK</option>
        <option value="closed" selected="true">Cancel</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr><br>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much